# Closing the splash screen from a different thread?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I'm using [WindowsFormsApplicationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx) to show a splash screen. Now, when the main form is created, and errors occur, a messagebox should be shown informing the user. However, the messagebox is displayed under the splash screen, so it's not visible. I need to close the splash screen so I can interact with the user.

The following code will give a cross-thread operation exception :

```
class SingleInstanceApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    private static SingleInstanceApplication instance;

    public static void CloseSplash()
    {
        if (instance.SplashScreen != null)
            instance.SplashScreen.Close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Splash' accessed from a thread 
other than the thread it was created on.
```

Is this even possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your splash screen form is named `mySplashScreen`:

```
mySplashScreen.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
    mySplashScreen.Close();
    mySplashScreen.Dispose();
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access user interface elements from a thread other than the one that created them.  Commonly one can use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) to access UI elements from other threads.

Comment: The generic way to do this is by using SynchronizationContext.Current to get the UI thread SynchronizationContext.  You then pass it to whatever works in the background or on a different thread.  They can then post delegates to the UI thread through it.