# Splash screen causing cross threading exception if startup form closed from code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, splash-screen

I've just inherited a legacy VB.Net project which runs fine in VS Community 2017 on a machine on the client's network, but when I try and run the code locally (on VS2017 Pro) I get an exception.

The project has the following properties set:

- Splash screen: SplashInvoice
- Startup form: SetupWizard

The code in SetupWizard form's load event checks a few thing and then closes itself if they are OK and opens another form:

```
Private Sub SetupWizard_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If [some conditions] Then
            frmMain.Show()
            Me.Close()
        Else
```

I'm getting this error when execution exits the `SetupWizard_Load` if the conditions are met and `me.close` is called:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'SplashInvoice' accessed from a thread other than the thread it
>   was created on.

If I comment out the `me.close` bit it all works fine.

So, it seems like closing the project's startup form while the project's splash screen is still showing is the issue, which leads to a couple of questions:

- Why does that cause an exception - isn't this all running on the main
  thread of execution?
- Why is this happening on my machine, but not on
  the dev machine?

This is the full stack trace:

> System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
>   exceptionInvoice
>   Generator.exeSystem.InvalidOperationException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Cross-thread
>   operation not valid: Control 'SplashInvoice' accessed from a thread other
>   than the thread it was created on.   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.Activate()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.HideSplashScreen()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.MainFormLoadingDone(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'SplashInvoice' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.Activate()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.HideSplashScreen()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.MainFormLoadingDone(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam) An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'SplashTest' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.
>
> The program '[50096] Invoice Generator.exe' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

Comment: Is the splash screen updated in any way during the start up of the program?  Can you provide a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Try running the project without the splash screen. Do you still get the  error?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I've updated the question to include the trace.  I'm also getting the error when I add a new splash screen with no code in it. I've searched the code and there's no reference to my new splash screen. Is there any way to refer to the currrent splash screen that doesn't involve calling it by name?

Comment: @preciousbetine, sorry, should have said that originally, no error without the splash screen

Comment: The stack trace says the exception occurs in a method named `MainFormLoadingDone` when it calls another method named `HideSplashScreen`.  Are any of these method running on a different thread?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I think both of those are part of the built in WinForms wiring that make the built in Splash Screen features work I think judging by their namespaces `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase`.  There are no such methods in the codebase.

Comment: Ah, I just spotted something, the project's `Startup form` checks some things and then closes itself and opens another form.  Changing the startup form seems to fix it, looks like that's something to do with it

Comment: @tomRedox - Yes, I missed that.  That's one reason I don't like to use all that VB application framework stuff.  You can't readily look at the code when diagnosing issues.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I agree, it was not a happy day when I was handed this blackbox of misery.. along with a form with 4k lines of code in.  I've got further into it now and worked out exactly where the issue is, but I still don't know why. 
 I've updated the question.

Comment: The splash runs on its own thread.  What is frmMain?   I suggest you read through [Extending the Visual Basic Application Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/customizing-extending-my/extending-the-visual-basic-application-model) to get an idea of how the splash screen is integrated into VB's Application Framework.

Comment: @TnTinMn:  Brilliant, that looks like exactly what I was looking for. "Visual Basic Application Model" is the terminology I was missing I think.  frmMain is the apps actual main screen, but the SetupWizard form is set as the Startup form.  When a new user runs the app the flow is that SplashInvoice shows, VB opens SetupWizard as the startup and that stays open.  For an exisiting user the flow is SplashInvoice shows, VB opens SetupWizard, SetupWizard opens frmMain and closes itself - that's when the exception comes on my machine (but not on the dev machine). Can you explain why?

Comment: Your project is likely setup to close when the last form closes.  When `Me.Close()` executes, the VB app-framework's MainForm property becomes set to SplashInvoice.  The `HideSplashScreen` method tries to _Activate_ MainForm (see your stack trace) and this is the source of the cross-thread exception as SplashInvoice is created on different thread.  I can not speculate on why you see the error surface on one machine and not the other.

Comment: Personally, I would disable the Application Framework and use a `Sub Main` to launch a customized version of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase`.  That way you could set the MainForm based on your _some conditions_, while still utilizing the base splash screen support, instead of creating a form that never shows when _some conditions_ is true.

Comment: @TnTinMn that's really good info, if you want to turn it into an answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before really understanding what was going on here I did manage to stop the exception by manually closing the splash screen in the start up form's `Load` event.  I added a call to the following method into that event:

```
private sub CloseSplash()

    Dim mySplash = My.Application.OpenForms.Item("SplashInvoice")

    mySplash.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
        mySplash.Close()
        mySplash.Dispose()
    End Sub))

End sub
```

That code [is based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7472031/1879019).

[@TnTinMn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) then provided some really useful information on all of this the comments and led to me to the Microsoft documentation on [Extending the Visual Basic Application Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/customizing-extending-my/extending-the-visual-basic-application-model)

That has this excellent diagram to explain how it all wires together:

[image: Visual Basic Application Model with SplashScreen]

That article also states

> ShowSplashScreen. Determines if the application has a splash screen
>   defined and if it does, displays the splash screen on a separate
>   thread.

Which appears to the be root of the issue I'm seeing.

@TnMinMn also made some really useful suggestions on how to fix this issue:

> Personally, I would disable the Application Framework and use a Sub
>   Main to launch a customized version of
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
>   That way you could set the MainForm based on your some conditions,
>   while still utilizing the base splash screen support, instead of
>   creating a form that never shows when some conditions is true